# Can I borrow a pointer to a shared trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

From the [tutorial on borrowed pointers](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial-borrowed-ptr.html) (broken), a bit modified:

```
struct Point {x: float, y: float}

fn compute(p1 : &Point) {}

fn main() {
    let shared_box : @Point = @Point {x: 5.0, y: 1.0};
    compute(shared_box);
}
```

And all is fine, because the shared box is automatically borrowed for the function.

But doing the same with a trait:

```
struct Point {x: float, y: float}
trait TPoint {}

impl TPoint for Point {}

fn compute(p1 : &TPoint) {}

fn main() {
    let shared_box : @TPoint = @Point {x: 5.0, y: 1.0} as @TPoint;

    compute(shared_box);
    //      ^~~~~~~ The error is here
}
```

And it fails, (compiler version 0.6) saying:

> error: mismatched types: expected `&TPoint` but found `@TPoint` (trait storage differs: expected & but found @)

Is this a bug in the compiler? Or are borrowed pointers not allowed for traits?

If the answer is the latter, why is that?

Comment: I am a little surprised by the error message you reported, since you are working with @TPoint and &TPoint in the code, but the error message reports a problem with ~TPoint and &TPoint.  (I suspect a transcription error that you may want to correct.)

Comment: @pnkfelix: Indeed, corrected. The same happens with `~TPoint` but the message didn't correspond with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in the current version of Rust:

[#3794: Casting to a trait doesn't auto-coerce to a &T type](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/3794)

There has been some work on trying to address this problem, but there are some technical details that need to be ironed out; interested parties can see some of the discussion (from a few months ago) [here on pull request 4178](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/4178).